# How to find that my retina device is using 2x image?

Tags: iphone, ios, retina-display

I know that 2x images are for retina display.

But i want to know that how can we identify that my device is using 1x image or 2x image?

and one more thing

I have one image name `stackOverflow.png` of size **50x50** and its 2x with name `stackOverflow@2x.png` of size **100x98**.

My question is that device will select retina image with name or size???

Comment: Simple answer for first question, add any extra mark on 2x image

Comment: Create one image 50x50 and on it write "50x50" and create one with dimen. 100x100 and on it write "100x100".

Comment: @Rajneesh071: It'll surely go for the name (AFAIK)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually not hard to tell just by looking at them-- especially in the iOS simulator. Set the simulator to retina mode and take a look. Non-retina images will be visibly blurry compared to retina images.

As for the image size, if your 2x image is not actually 2x the size of the original image, **you are doing it wrong**. Fix one image or the other, or both. Retina images are selected by name. If the size is wrong, the image will be stretched to fit. That will ruin the high-resolution retina effect you're trying to get with a 2x image.

Answer (score 5):

To check which one has been loaded, you can use this code:

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];
    NSLog(@"scale: %f", image.scale); //this will be 2.0 for retina image
```

Or just simply use two different images, as @MidhunMP suggested in comments.

Comment: thanks i used 2 diff image with different size... and i found that retina image will select according to name...there is no effect if we use with diff size....